# how i can select those records in which same row and in same column value is repeated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

like i have a file with attributes or columns fullname, addressln1, city, state, zip
and someone just mass up that files and in some records fullname column name come up like "joe joe David"
or "syed hashim Ali syed" i just want to select those records and take out from file to fix them can i do that in sql or excell please please help me out
                                                                Thanx

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume you have a column called `data_quality` in your `addresses` table.

```
class Addess < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save :set_data_quality

  def set_data_quality
   names = self.fullname.downcase.split
   data_quality = "poor" if names.size > names.uniq.size 
  end

end
```

After the import, the rows with duplicate names will have the column `data_quality` set to `poor`.